# CSS Bootstrap Alternating Stacking

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have three rows, each row containing an image, and text. I want the layout of the rows to alternate the image positioning when *not* stacked, but maintain a uniform stacked layout on smaller screens. such as this:

large screen

row 1: img1 left, img1-text right 
 
row 2: img2-text left, img2 right 
row 3: img3 left, img3-text right

small screen

img1 
img1-text 
img2 
img2-text 
img3 
img3-text

I attempted to deal with this by adding duplicate image's and hiding and showing the respective img's accordingly, but I don't like this method. How can I achieve my desired results? Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="row">

    <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <img class="img img-fluid" src="img/crowd-of-users.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <h2>lorem ipsum.</h2>
      <h7>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h7>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
          <img class="show-alt img img-fluid" src="img/strategy (1).svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <h7>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h7>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <img class="hide-alt img img-fluid" src="img/strategy (1).svg"/>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <img class="img img-fluid" src="img/money (1).svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
      <h7>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h7>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.img {
    width:50%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .btf {
    padding-top:10%;
  }
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .hide-alt {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width:768px){
   .show-alt {
     display: none;
   } 
  }
```

And if there's an existing SO entry that I missed, feel free to point it out, I was unsure of the keywords to use to find my answer, cheers

Comment: It appears as though you're using Bootstrap there. Can you confirm if this is the case or not? If it is, note that columns **must** add up to 12; one of your three rows does not.

Comment: bootstrap is a part of the project, yes. each row has an img (col-sm-5) and text (col-sm-7). so each row adds up to 12 already. you might be counting the alt-img's. but I figured if these were hidden at certain breakpoints, bootstrap wouldn't recognize them, and it seems that im correct in that assumption

Comment: the one with the extra img (row 2) is the reason im asking this question. because I I want the side the image is on to alternate. row 1 has img on left, row 2 on right, row 3 on left

Comment: I feel like this is a great use case for `d-flex flex-row` then the alternate row would be `flex-row-reverse`. Use flexbox, and use the columns inside the flexbox to give it a bit of rigidity while being super flexible.

Comment: I.R.R...you're great! was not aware of this aspect of bootstrap...much appreciated!